# Give an example of a non-zero function $ f ∈ L^2 ( Z (2))$ such that $Ff=−f$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-transform

Give an example of a non-zero function $ f ∈ L^2 ( Z (2))$ such that $Ff=−f$.
This is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue−1.)

I am extremely bad at questions like this and would love to have a better understanding or maybe suggestions on how to learn how to answer questions like this.

This question is asking what non-zero function gets the opposite of the function when you take the Fourier transform

Comment: What is $Z(2)$?

Comment: Also, what is $F$?

Comment: F is the Fourier transform